# detect the meaning of words using a dictionary online

Tags: python-3.x

When I use a dictionary online to get a meanging of a idiom, it gives a long text. I need only the meaning of the idiom.
for example: if i need to know the meaning of the idiom:birds of a feather
first I have to type bird. The result will be a long descriptio,and I need only the "birds of a feather" one. So I need to print the idiom with the meaning only.

```
for term in mylist: # a list of multiword term that I need to have their meaning
    ws = term.split()
    meaning = ""
    url = "https://mydictionary" + ws[0]+ "" # search the mwt with the first term
    if urllib.request.urlopen(url):
        htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlfile, 'lxml')
        txt = soup.text
        if term in txt:
            meaning =txt[txt.index(term):.... ]
```

How can I get it?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. What is `mylist`, for example?

Comment: mwt = multiword terms

Comment: Can you post an example of the large text it gives you and what you want to retrieve from that text?